# Share audio output device between two processes

Tags: alsa, pipewire

Is it possible for 2 processes, each trying to send audio to the single output device, to share (mix) the audio streams?

I'm running AlmaLinux 9 and have paired back to basic ALSA only.  But if needed I can add (back) pipewire.

I want to test using 'aplay' but the solution should work with any process' audio output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for 2 processes, each trying to send audio to the single output device, to share (mix) the audio streams?

Yes, that's what an audio server is for. So, using pipewire instantly solves this – it even offers a (software-implemented) ALSA pseudodevice that any ALSA-using program can use.

Comment: So ALSA doesn't support this but pipewire does?  (So I'll have to add this back)

Comment: see the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that "ALSA" is not an audio server, but pipewire is.  (If correct, I suggest adding to response for us less informed)  Thx

Comment: Yes that is correct. I already say that in the answer - alsa offers *devices*.